# nmap cant find VM host ip

Tags: nmap, virtualbox

I have a homework exercise where I need to use nmap on my PC and have Windows XP running on a VM (Using VirtualBox). But when scanning my network it doesn't seem to find the VM running.

```
nmap -n -Pn 192.168.2.1
```

I get a list of IPs but not the one I need.

When I use `ipconfig` I get:

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network: 192.168.56.1

IP in VirtualBox 192.168.2.17
```

The network I'm using in VirtualBox is 'Bridged Adapter'

So my question is, what could cause nmap not to find the IPs of the VM? and if it does, which IP will it show? 192.168.56.1 or 192.168.2.17?

I'm not studying Network/Security, this is the only course related to it that I have to take. So I'm kind of lost about everything here.

Comment: your nmap command is only scanning the 192.168.2.1 system. its not looking for other IPs. if you wanted to scan the whole .2.0 subnet, use `nmap -n -Pn 192.168.2.0/24` or alternately you could use `nmap -n -Pn 192.168.2.1-254`  https://www.stationx.net/nmap-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 1):

> Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network: 192.168.56.1

Host Only is designed to be secure from outside connections.

Try the default NAT connection instead and nmap will likely then work.

You should be able to check network connections with PING to make sure networks are working correctly.

Comment: I've tried using NAT but it wasn't able to find it either. Getting a bunch of IP addresses, but not the one of the VM

Comment: Try using Bridged Networking.  Also try a more modern guest.  XP is long out of support.  I tried nmap here from Ubunutu to another guest in VMware and that worked fine.

Comment: Just to confirm, nmap is working from Ubuntu to Kali on my NAT subnet and either guest to my Windows 11 Host on my router subnet.  Again try a more modern guest and also check your network connections with PING.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to be able to find your virtual machine via network from host, you need to connect your host with the guest (virtual machine) in the same network.

Thus you need to first create a host-only network by File -> Host Network Management. Then create a network. The default name should be vboxnet0.

[image: Screenshot Host-Only Network Preference]

Then in the network setting of the guest, chose attach to Host-only Adapter.

[image: Screenshot Host-only Adaptor setting]

By now the host and the guest is connected to a network via a switch. Personally I found vmware's explanation is clearer. See the link for detail:

- [vmware's documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Linux/16.0/com.vmware.player.linux.using.doc/GUID-93BDF7F1-D2E4-42CE-80EA-4E305337D2FC.html)
- [virtualbox's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/network_hostonly.html).

Then make sure that the guest is assigned with an IP address (can be multiple). If not, enable DHCP Server from Host Network Management settings.

[image: Screenshot DHCP Settings]

If you are running windows in virtual machine, you can run `ipconfig` in cmd to see whether the guest is assigned with an IP address. Or other equivalent tool for other OS.

To scan the entire network, you should add respective prefix length such as `nmap 192.168.56.0/24`
You should be able to find the guest by now. You can also try to ping the guest using the IP address from the result of `ipconfig` from the guest.

Comment: Nice writeup :-) Slightly inaccurate, tho. There's `VirtualBox Host-Only Network: 192.168.56.1', host's Host-Only network IP address. The OP says they've configured a bridged adapter and VM:s IP is 192.168.2.17. They're scanning this network, so their host's range is 192.168.2.0/24. When the adapter is bridged, VM gets IP from the same network with the host and is pingable / scannable. So creating host-only adapter isn't really an appropriate solution here. The likely point of failure is, as others have stated, the stone-age guest OS which doesn't necessarily play well with current solutions.